$a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^+: abc = 1.$ Show that $\left(\dfrac{1}{a^3+1}+\dfrac{1}{b^3+1}+\dfrac{1}{c^3+1}\right)\le\dfrac{(a+b+c)^3}{18}$
$a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^+: abc = 1.$ Show that $\left(\dfrac{1}{a^3+1}+\dfrac{1}{b^3+1}+\dfrac{1}{c^3+1}\right)\le\dfrac{(a+b+c)^3}{18}$
I ran into this inequality problem online and have been spinning my wheels trying to prove it.
Here are a few things I've tried:

Using Cauchy-Schwarz: $(a + b + c)\left(\dfrac{a^2}{6} + \dfrac{b^2}{6} + \dfrac{c^2}{6}\right) \ge \dfrac{(a + b + c)^3}{18}$. Multiplying out the LHS didn't get me anywhere.
Using AM-GM: $\dfrac{1}{a^3} + \dfrac{1}{b^3} + \dfrac{1}{c^3} \ge \dfrac{9}{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}$

$\implies \dfrac{1}{2\left(\dfrac{1}{a^3} + \dfrac{1}{b^3} + \dfrac{1}{c^3}\right)} = \dfrac{\frac12}{(ab)^3 + (bc)^3 + (ac)^3} \le \dfrac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{18}$
I thought about applying the same identity to each term on the problem's LHS, so for example $\dfrac{1}{a^3 +1} \le \dfrac{1}{a^3} + \dfrac{1}{1}.$ However, I couldn't get the sum of all the new terms on the RHS to be the original problem's RHS, and this application seems premature as it imposes $a = b = c = 1,$ which makes everything defined and additional uses of inequality would be irrelevant.

Since it's easy to guess that equality occurs when $a = b = c = 1$, I thought about making the $LHS = 0$ by substracting $\dfrac12$ from each term.

E.g. $\dfrac{1}{a^3 + 1} - \dfrac12 = \dfrac12.\dfrac{1 - a^3}{1 + a^3}$
This seemed promising but I wasn't able to get anything from it.

I also tried reducing the LHS to a common denominator. This was last resort and it also seemed to reach a dead end. This is the result I got, with $(abc)^3 = 1$:

$LHS = \dfrac{3 + 2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + \frac{1}{a^3} + \frac{1}{b^3} + \frac{1}{c^3}}{2 + a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + \frac{1}{a^3} + \frac{1}{b^3} + \frac{1}{c^3}}$

Throughout those attempts, I also tried replacing 1 with $abc$ or $(abc)^3$ whenever I felt it could produce something. E.g. $\dfrac{1}{a^3 + 1} = \dfrac{1}{a^3 + abc} = \dfrac{abc}{a^3 + abc} = \dfrac{bc}{a^2 + bc}.$

These are pretty much the main things I've tried. I did extend some of those efforts further yet to nowhere meaningful so for brevity I didn't detail those here.
I hope to receive some hints.
Thanks!

Here's how to ask a good question. Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

@jjagmath Thanks! I just thought some of my attempts weren't getting anywhere so I didn't want to cause people to read unnecessarily longer. I will edit the post and outline what I've tried.

One way to solve this problem is to use the well-known Cirtoaje's inequality $\sum\limits_{x,y,z}\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\ge 1$ that holds for real $x,y,z>0$ such that $xyz=1$. It can be proved by taking $x=\frac{uv}{t^2},\ y=\frac{vt}{u^2},\ z=\frac{tu}{v^2}$ and applying Cauchy-Schwarz.
As for the main inequality, by Schur and AM-GM we have $$\begin{aligned}\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{18}&\ge\frac{4(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-9abc}{18}\\&\ge\frac{4(a+b+c)\cdot 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}-9abc}{18}=\frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)-\frac{1}{2}\end{aligned}$$ Therefore it suffices to prove $$\sum\limits_{a,b,c}\left(\frac{2}{3}a-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{a^3+1}\right)\ge 0$$ Notice that for $a=b=c=1$ we have equality.
Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{x^3+1}-\frac{k}{x^{2m}+x^m+1}+\frac{k}{3}$ on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. By choosing suitable constants $k,m$, we want $f$ to be nonnegative with the minimum at $x=1$. From $f'(1)=0$ we have $m=-\frac{17}{4k}$. From $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)\ge 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x)\ge 0$ we have $k\ge\frac{7}{2}$. Choosing for convenience $k=\frac{17}{4}$ we obtain $m=-1$ yielding explicitly $$f(x)=\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{x^3+1}-\frac{\frac{17}{4}}{x^{-2}+x^{-1}+1}+\frac{\frac{17}{4}}{3}=\frac{(x-1)^2\left(8x^4-12x^3-9x^2+17x+3\right)}{12\left(x^3+1\right)\left(x^2+x+1\right)}$$ Since $$8x^4-12x^3-9x^2+17x+3=3\left(x^2-1\right)^2+3(x-2)^2x^2+\left(2x^3-15x+17\right)x$$ and $$2x^3+\frac{17}{2}+\frac{17}{2}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{2x^3\cdot\frac{17^2}{4}}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{16\cdot 18}{2}}x=3\sqrt[3]{12^2}x>3\sqrt[3]{5^3}x=15x$$ hence $f(x)\ge 0$ meaning that also $$f(a)+f(b)+f(c)\ge 0$$ or equivalently $$\sum\limits_{a,b,c}\left(\frac{2}{3}a-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{a^3+1}\right)\ge\frac{17}{4}\sum\limits_{a,b,c}\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^2+\frac{1}{a}+1}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\ge 0$$ where the last inequality holds by $\sum\limits_{x,y,z}\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\ge 1$.
Equality in the main inequality occurs iff $a=b=c=1$.

Some thoughts.
Using the known identity $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca)$ and AM-GM, we have
$$(a+b+c)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc + 3(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\ge a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 24.$$
(Note: $a + b + c \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$ and
$ab + bc + ca \ge 3\sqrt[3]{ab\cdot bc \cdot ca}$.)
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{a^3+1}+\frac{1}{b^3+1}+\frac{1}{c^3+1}
\le \frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 24}{18}.$$
Let $x = a^3, y = b^3, z = c^3$. It suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, z > 0$ with $xyz = 1$,
$$\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{y+1}+\frac{1}{z+1}
\le \frac{x + y + z + 24}{18}.$$
This inequality is true. The remaining part is smooth, e.g. by the pqr method.
